# Unexpected Java AssertionError thrown: expecting null after re-instantiation of a static object

Tags: java, junit, assertions

I'm writing a simple JUnit test for a excel report reader method and this particular one is testing the mapping of existing engine objects to row indexes in the report. 
For this particular test I'm getting a result when I actually expect the test to return null.

global variables :

```
    private static Engine engineOnRow7;
    Map<Engine, Integer> actual= new HashMap<Engine, Integer>();
```

1. For my first assertion I create a new `Engine` object with some parameters and put it in a HashMap, all the assertions pass as expected:

   ```
   engineOnRow7 = new Engine(a,b,c)
   expected.put(engineOnRow7, 7);
   Integer row = actual.get(engineOnRow7);
   assertNotNull(row);
   assertTrue((int)row == 7);
   ```
2. I then re-instantiate the object with the same parameters and perform another `get` operation on the map expecting the result to be null (as it's a "new" object):

   ```
   engineOnRow7 = new Engine(a,b,c)
   row = actual.get(engineOnRow7);
   assertNull(row);
   ```

However, the above throws an `AssertionError` saying the actual value of `row` is still 7.

My initial thoughts are that the map is still using the old `engineOnRow7' reference because it's a static object and that is why it's finding a result of 7 and not null. However I'm not entirely sure, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. 
This is my first ever stack overflow post and I realise the question title is quite vague/ I might not have given enough context to what I'm trying to achieve so if any additional information is required please comment and I'll do my best to provide.

Comment: You never show how the `actual` variable is initialised.

Comment: Indeed. A [mcve] would make it easier to help you.

Comment: I'll take a look at that link, thanks @JonSkeet.

Comment: @ScottBarbour include all updates directly in the question [by editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34132373/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `actual` a `HashMap` like `expected`?
If so, then the key will depend on `Engine` class's `hashCode` and `equals` methods.
I guess that both the original and the reinstantiated `Engine` objects have the same hash code and are equal. So they will both point to the same value in a `HashMap`.

Comment: Yes it is the same I've just been hasty and added the wrong line of code. Thanks for the feedback, I done a quick google on hashcodes and that seems to be the answer to my problem. Thank you!